# bubble sort string array

Tags: java, sorting

I'm trying to use a bubble sort to alphabetize an array that I've read into a program. The code compiles without error but I get an Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception on my 'if' construct when I try to run the program. I have initialized int i to 0 to account for the first index of the array so I think my error is elsewhere. I'm not asking anyone to write code for me, just maybe a point in the right direction. Thanks for any help.

```
public static String[] bubbleSort(String[] inL)
{
    String temp;
    int i = 0, passNum;

    for(passNum = 1; passNum <= (inL.length); i++)  // controls passes through bubble sort
    {
        if(inL[i].compareToIgnoreCase(inL[i + 1]) < 0)
        {
            temp = inL[i];
            inL[i] = inL[i + 1];
            inL[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }

    return inL; // returns sorted array 
} // end bubbleSort method
```

Answer (score 2):

You compare `passNum` instead of `i` against the length of the array. Since `passNum` is never modified, the loop condition is always true, and `i` gets incremented until it exceeds the range of the array.

Even if this particular issue is resolved, you may still run into problems with off-by-one errors with your current implementation. Consider whether you should compare `i` against `inL.length - 1`.

Comment: I realized after reading the answers here that my problem was more than an incorrect boolean operator or variable intialization. I went through my code with a debugger and found my problems. I should have done that before coming here but I wanted to say thanks to you and the others who helped me. I will not be so quick to post for help in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You never increment `passNum` so `i` continues incrementing forever. Also, array indexing in Java is based at 0. That means that the largest valid index is `inL.length - 1`. Since the body of your loop accesses `inL[i+1]`, you should arrange your code so that `i` never exceeds `inL.length - 2`. At a minimum, you should change `<=` to `<` in the `for` loop termination test. (However, the logic of your comparison and incrementing escapes me; you need to fix that as well.)

Answer (score 0):

`Array.length` stores the total length of an array, starting counting at 1.

The first index in an array however is 0, meaning that the last index is `length-1`.

adjust your check in your for-loop to fix the error

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `passNum <= (inL.length)` it should be `passNum < (inL.length)` due to 0 being the first index of an array in java